# Getting the src attribute of an image within a parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, src, attr

I have a list of images, one of which gets a class="selected" after a change occurs on the page:

```
<div id="selectable"> 
    <li>
        <img src="\images\1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <img src="\images\2.jpg" />  
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="\images\3.jpg" />  
    </li>
</div>
```

I want to be able to capture the value of the image's src attribute, so I can use it later...
I'm thinking something like this:

```
$("#selectable").change(function() {
    var src = $('li[class="selected"]').attr('src');
    alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + src);
}
```

But I need it to get the value of the src attribute of the **child** element (img).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("li.selected").find("img").attr("src");
```

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to be able to capture the value of the image's src attribute, so I can use it later...*

```
var src = ''; // DEFINE VARIABLE OUTSIDE

$('#selectable li').click(function(){  // USE CLICK EVENT
   src = $('img', this).attr('src');
   // alert( src )
});
```

To target directly the desired image use:

```
// some event
    $('#selectable li.selected img').attr('src');
//
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using below code.

```
var src = $('li.selected img').attr('src');
-------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgsrc="";

    $("#selectable li").click(function() {

        var imgsrc= $('li.selected img').attr('src');

        alert( imgsrc);
    }
```

Comment: `$("#selectable").change(function() {` are you serious

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var src = $('li[class="selected"]').attr('src');
```

to

```
var src = $('li[class="selected"]').find('img').attr('src');
```

More on jQuery [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like this:

```
var src=$('#selectable > li.selected > img').attr('src');
alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + src);
```

**An example**

HTML:

```
<div id="selectable"> 
    <li>
        <img src="\images\1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <img src="\images\2.jpg" />  
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="\images\3.jpg" />  
    </li>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#selectable li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + src);
});
```

See **Jquery selector techniques** for more details:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/